# It return false instead of true

Tags: java, regex

How to match "FileNew" in "FileNewABC" which is a value from f_var and return true?

```
newfilename = Pattern.compile("FileNew").matcher(f_var).matches();
```

It always return false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `find` or it will try and match entire input to the pattern.

- The matches method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.
- The lookingAt method attempts to match the input sequence, starting at the beginning, against the pattern.
- The find method scans the input sequence looking for the next subsequence that matches the pattern.

Comment: Congrats for achieving 5 digits ;)